# Database connection pooling using temporary table

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using Apache dbcp for connection pooling and ibatis to do the database transactions with spring support. The scenario that i am trying to workout is:

1. create BasicDataSource with max initial connection as 5
2. Create a temp table
3. Write bulk of records in temp table.
4. Write the records onto actual table.
5. Delete the temp table

The issue here is step 2-5 runs in multi threaded mode. Also since i am using connection pooling, i cannot guranatee that sttep 2,3,4,5 will get the same connection object from the pool and hence i see in step 3/4/5 that temp table XYZ not found.

How can i gurantee that i can reuse the same connection accross the 4 operations. Here's the code for step 3 and 4. I am not thinking to use Global temp table.

```
@Transactional  
public final void insertInBulk(final List<Rows> rows) {  
getSqlMapClientTemplate().execute(new SqlMapClientCallback<Object>() {  
    public Object doInSqlMapClient(  
        SqlMapExecutor exe) throws SQLException {  
            executor.startBatch();  
            for (Rows row : rows) {  
                for (Object row : row.getMultiRows()) {  
                    exe.insert("##TEMPTABLE.insert", row);  
                }  
            }  
            exe.executeBatch();  
            return null;  
     }});
```

}

```
public void copyValuesToActualTable() {  
    final Map<String, Object> procInput = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
    procInputMap.put("tableName", "MYTABLE");  
    getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("##TEMPTABLE.NAME", procInput);  
}
```

I am thinking of improving the design further by creating temp table just once when connection is initialised and instead of dropping truncate the table but one for later and will still have issues with step 3 and 4. Reason for temp table is i dont have access (permission) to directly modify the actual table but via temp table.

Comment: Fix errors in the source code

Answer (score 0):

I would actually create the temp table (step 2) in the main thread, then break the workload of inserting records in to temp table (Step 3 and Step 4) into chunks and spawn thread for each chunk.

JDK 7 provides the [ForkJoin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) for this step that you may be interested.

Once the insertion into temp and actual table is done, then delete the temp table again in the main thread.

In this way, you don't need to ensure that the same connection is being used everywhere. You can use different connection objects to the same database and perform the step 3 & 4 in parallel.

Hope this helps.